# Express server unreachable from browser when running in WSL2

Tags: node.js, express, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

So, I have been trying to start a basic express server from inside WSL2 on port 3000. Every time I go to the browser, it says that "localhost:3000" is unreachable. I'm not really sure where the problem is. I have been able to start and access react applications that are running on port 3000 in WSL2 without a problem. Additionally, I have been able to start Flask servers from other ports on my machine from within WSL2 without a problem. The issue somehow seems isolated to Express JS servers, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

I have confirmed that the app is exposed on all interfaces, so localhost should be reachable.
When starting the application, I have been monitoring it with `netstat -ltp`. The node process does show up in the output, which indicates that the port is listening.

Are there any weird WSL2 configuration steps that I missed. The strange part is that other applications that don't use Express JS, applications seem to be running perfectly fine on all ports.

I also already have all local ports accessible through the Windows Firewall and have made the ports accessible on the Windows side via this command: `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3000 connectaddress=127.0.0.x`

I have also been testing this using `npx express-generator your-project-name --no-view` to create a standard Express JS template.

Update:
The server is reachable from the IP address on my network, but unreachable from localhost.

Comment: can you share your code for express?

Comment: I used `npx express-generator your-project-name --no-view` to create a standard base express application

Comment: Can you share the code generated by
Generator and also what commands you are using to run the main file?

Comment: I used to `node index.js` to start the application
The code I used can be found here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html
This page shows the project structure created by the generator: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: Ah, ok, so a quick update: the server is reachable from the IP address on my network, but not reachable from localhost.

Comment: @RohinDasari `netsh interface portproxy`[...] shouldn't `connectaddress` be the WSL ip address? I don't think `127.0.0.x` is a valid value. You can check WSL address running `ifconfig`